# How to by-pass "VHD_BOOT_HOST_VOLUME_NOT_ENOUGH_SPACE" when native-booting?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, hyper-v, vhd

With Hyper-V, I created a expandable VHDX file with Windows 10 installed inside, whose max-size just equals the size of the partition it stores. Blue screen came out saying "VHD_BOOT_HOST_VOLUME_NOT_ENOUGH_SPACE" when **native-booting**.

I know **M$ requires** that there must be free space on the partition in case VHDX expands to maximum. (Plus the space of the page-file, as is said in  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/understanding-virtual-hard-disks-with-native-boot) .)

It means if you claim that much space, it must be reserved, no matter allocated to a traditional partition, occupied by a fixed-sized VHDX, or just left on the disk for an expandable VHDX (though may shared by multiple ones).

However, I would like to **take care of it myself** to utilize the free space not yet used. Since the VHDX will be my system drive, it is hardly possible that I wouldn't notice it before it grows too large.

I wonder if there are any tricks to by-pass this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an entry `VirtualDiskExpandOnMount` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\FsDepends\Parameters` in the registry that can be set to the value `4`, to [disable the expending](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/gg318055(v=ws.10)#step-12-prevent-the-vhd-from-expanding-to-its-full-size) of the VHDs.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Should I edit it inside the VHDX? Outside the VHDX there is no Windows installed on the physical drive, but a Windows boot-loader contained in folder \Boot and folder \EFI, which will load the VHDX while native-booting.

Comment: configure this inside the registry of the Windows that is inside the VHD.

Comment: @magicandre1981 how can you configure the registry inside the VHD windows if you can't even boot it.

Comment: @RedaDrissi mount the VHD, run [regedit, load hive and edit the value](https://4sysops.com/archives/regedit-as-offline-registry-editor/)

Comment: @RedaDrissi does it work?

Comment: I managed to make wine work and settled for a container instead. I needed a .NET windows application on a linux host and for my use case wine was enough. So I didn't try it. But if I ever try it I'll post my feedback here.

Comment: Thank you worked for me